# How to connect a django app to bokeh server?

Tags: python, django, bokeh

I'm currently trying out bokeh server to serve some interactive bokeh charts to my django app, but having difficulty connecting via `views.py`.

The browser returns an OSError:

```
Cannot pull session document because we failed to connect to the server (to start the server, try the 'bokeh serve' command)
```

The server itself returns 404 error for the request:

```
200-03-31 08:17:09,179 404 GET /ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=ZhGn4XcmC1qDPYtF4SRPGPa1GzSgTqktqmvkIEGJke26 (127.0.0.1) 0.55ms
```

My server is set up as follows:

```
bokeh_server
|
|--main.py
```

`main.py` is a very basic bokeh chart

***main.py***

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=list(range(5)), y=list(range(5))))
p = figure(width=300, height=300, tools=[], toolbar_location=None, name="test")
p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source)
curdoc().add_root(column(p, sizing_mode='scale_width'))
```

Running the server (`bokeh serve bokeh_server`) and then opening `https://localhost:5006` in a browser renders the chart correctly (`https://localhost:5006/bokeh_server`)

The issue comes when I try to open it from my django app.

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bokeh.client import pull_session

def testbserver(request):
    session = pull_session(url="http://localhost:5006/")
    script = server_session(model=None,
                            session_id=None,
                            url="http://localhost:5006/",
                            )
    return render(request, 'testserver.html', {'script':script})
```

***urls.py***

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('testbserver/', views.testbserver, name='testbserver'),
]
```

***testserver.html***

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    {{script | safe }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried running the server with websockets allowed (`bokeh serve bokeh_server/ --allow-websocket-origin="*" --log-level trace`) but still get the same error.

Any suggestions for other things to try are gratefully received!

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/howto/server_embed/django_embed

Comment: Thanks - that helped.  I needed to specify the directory names in both the urls, ("http://localhost:5006/bokeh_server") and also import server_session from bokeh.embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Eugene Pakhomov for the pointers, needed to update `views.py` to:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bokeh.client import pull_session
from bokeh.embed import server_session

def testbserver(request):
    session = pull_session(url="http://localhost:5006/bokeh_server")
    script = server_session(model=None,
                            session_id=session.id,
                            url="http://localhost:5006/bokeh_server",
                            )
    return render(request, 'testserver.html', {'script':script})
```

There was also an issue in the testserver.html - I wasn't making the script safe:

testserver.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

<head>
<link href = "https://cdn.pydata.org./bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" >
<link href = "https://cdn.pydata.org./bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" >
<link href = "https://cdn.pydata.org./bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.4.0.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" >

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.pydata.org./bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"> </script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.pydata.org./bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"> </script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.pydata.org./bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.4.0.min.js"> </script>

<h1>Test</h1>
{{script | safe}}
</head> 
<div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">

<body>
    {{div | safe}}
</body>

{% endblock %}
```